# How to copy missing column values from previous row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv file, which contains missing column values, how to copy missing column value from previous row ?

```
product_id,name,modifier
1,test,cheese
,test,eggs
,test,onions
2,test2,cheese
,test2,eggs
,test2,onions
```

Above CSV data, gets below output

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("pivot-products.csv")
df.pivot(index='product_id',columns='modifier') # <-- throws error
```

Above pivot code works fine with below dataset, where I manually copied it, how to cleanup in pandas to look like below ?

```
product_id,name,modifier
1,test,cheese
1,test,eggs
1,test,onions
2,test2,cheese
2,test2,eggs
2,test2,onions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `ffill`. For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv("pivot-products.csv")
df["product_id"] = df["product_id"].ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['product_id'].ffill(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

but look specifically for the `method='ffill'` option

Answer (score 1):

```py
df.fillna(mehtod='ffill').fillna(value)
```

You do [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) twice because the 'ffill' will fail to fill nan values in the first row. You can define the `value`.